# Python ConfigParser - module object is not callable in Fedora 23

Tags: python-2.7, configparser

Trying to read an .ini db file from python to test a connection to a PostGres database

Python Version 2.7.11

In Fedora, I installed with

### sudo dnf install python-configparser

Install  1 Package

Total download size: 41 k
Installed size: 144 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:

### python-configparser-3.5.0b2-0.2.fc23.noarch.rpm  40 kB/s |  41 kB     00:01

Total                                            31 kB/s |  41 kB     00:01
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Installing  : python-configparser-3.5.0b2-0.2.fc23.noarch                 1/1
  Verifying   : python-configparser-3.5.0b2-0.2.fc23.noarch                 1/1

Installed:
  python-configparser.noarch 3.5.0b2-0.2.fc23

---

in my config.py I do a

import configparser

when I run my script I get 'module' object is not callable

**db.ini**

```
[test1]
host=IP address
database=db
port=5432
user=username
password=pswd

[test2]
host=localhost
database=postgres
port=7999
user=abc
password=abcd
```

**config.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#from configparser import ConfigParser
import configparser


def config(filename='database.ini', section='gr'):
    # create a parser
    parser = configparser()
    # read config file
    parser.read(filename)

    # get section, default to gr
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

    return db
```

**testing.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import psycopg2
from config import config



def connect():
    """ Connect to the PostgreSQL database server """
    conn = None
    try:
        # read connection parameters
        params = config()

        # connect to the PostgreSQL server
        print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)

        # create a cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()

 # execute a statement
        print('PostgreSQL database version:')
        cur.execute('SELECT version()')

        # display the PostgreSQL database server version
        db_version = cur.fetchone()
        print(db_version)

     # close the communication with the PostgreSQL
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
            print('Database connection closed.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

[root@svr mytest]# ./testing.py
'module' object is not callable

any ideas ? 
thank you.

Comment: can you provide full traceback please?

Comment: add an __init__.py in the same directory as testing.py, this is probably an import configuration fault

Comment: do I need to do the configparser import in that __init.py__ file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your parser creation, see the [ConfigParser examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#examples):

> An example of reading the configuration file again:
>
> ```
> import ConfigParser
>
> config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
> config.read('example.cfg')
> ```

In Python, [a module is basically just a file](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), so if you want to use anything from this module, you have to specify *what* from the module you want. In your case, change the lines to

```
# create a parser
parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
```

This way, you are using the class `ConfigParser` from the module.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the follow to import the parser:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
```

instead of

```
import configparser
```

I had the same issue as you and this worked for me.